# git rebase with git_committer_name and git_committer_email

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to rebase diverged branch onto feature branch.

Ideally this should work without problem.

```
git checkout featureA
git rebase dev
git checkout dev
git merge featureA
```

But it changes some commits commiter name and email to my name and email which is really mean.

I know how to modify history using filter-branch but I don't want to do it.

Is there a way to provide environment variables like **GIT_COMMITTER_NAME** and **GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL** to `git rebase` for every commit being processed?

Comment: The thing is that `git rebase` actually _does_ re-commit everything on top of the new branch, so changing the committer is technically correct. IMHO it is also valuable information as you are the last one who touched the commit, so setting you as the committer enables others to get back to you in case of questions.

Comment: And it preserves AUTHOR_NAME and AUTHOR_EMAIL, so you're not losing the original author information.